# shell export variable not come into effect

Tags: linux, macos, shell, unix

I (on mac osx) often use

> export http_proxy=http://192.168.0.205:1099

to proxy http connection to get a highed download speed. To make things easy， I wrote a shell file named **proxy.sh** to do this:

```
#!/bin/sh
export http_proxy=http://192.168.0.205:1099
```

Before I downlaod, I execute proxy.sh shell command, but I found it did't not come into effect.It lost http_proxy variable in current commnad window(terminal). I must type export command in current terminal,it will come into effect.

So I want to know what's reason for this and a solution? thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Running a shell script "normally" (with `proxy.sh` for example) results in that running in a sub-process so that it cannot affect the environment of the parent process.

Using `.` or `source` will run the shell script in the context of the current shell, so it *will* be able to affect the environment, using one of the following:

```
. proxy.sh
source proxy.sh
```

Another possibility (if you're using `bash` at least) is to create an alias to do the work for you. You can use something like:

```
alias faster='export http_proxy=http://192.168.0.205:1099'
```

so that you can then simply type `faster` on the command line and it will export that variable (in the context of the current shell).

You could also allow for one-shot settings such as:

```
alias faster='http_proxy=http://192.168.0.205:1099'
```

and then use:

```
faster your_program
```

which would translate into:

```
http_proxy=http://192.168.0.205:1099 your_program
```

That's a `bash` way to set a variable for just the *one* invocation of a command.

Answer (score 5):

The export variable will only apply to the script -- if you want it to apply to the shell, you need to use source, and execute the script like so:

```
. ./proxy.sh
```

or:

```
source ./proxy.sh
```

Note the "." in the first example -- the dot follow by space means the script will apply to the shell.

Answer (score 3):

The reason why your script does not work has been explained by Drakosha & how to make your script work has been explained by Anothony. But with the export in the script *you need to source your script each time you open a new terminal*. A better solution will be to add the export in [`.bash_profile`](http://www.devdaily.com/blog/post/mac-os-x/sample-mac-osx-bashrc-terminal-startup-file) or [`.bashrc`](http://notes.vacantcanvas.com/development/enabling-bashrc-on-os-x-10-6-snow-leopard/)
Hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

When executing a shell script a **new** shell is launched, the script is executed, and the shell dies. That's why you don't see the variable defined in your shell.

I suggest using an alias for the same purpose.